# Why was my "opinion-based" flag declined?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags

I was trying to flag a question that seemed to be a purely opinion-based question, but the flag got declined afterward.

I looked back into the question and found that it was then put on hold as primarily opinion based. Why was my flag got declined?

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Using standard flags helps prioritize problems and resolve them faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags. If you had used a close flag instead of a custom flag, the question would have been put into the close queue, where it would be reviewed by normal users with experience in the technology being asked about instead of the high priority moderator only queue that custom flags push posts into.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As the decline message stated, please use *standard* flags where possible. This lets us prioritize our queue properly.

In this particular case, flags to close a question don't require moderator intervention, and can be handled by the community. Custom flags (which you used) go directly to moderators, rather than allowing the community to shoulder the load.

Please have a read of the [help on flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts). If you believe a question is off-topic, please select 'should be closed' when flagging the question:

> [image]

You then get to choose the reason. In this case, 'primarily opinion based':

> [image]

Comment: You have a very steady hand :p